Trigger (static_) assert when compiler is able to determine parameter constant at compile time
Consider the following code:
Live demo
#include <iostream>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <assert.h>

struct MyFile
{

    MyFile(const char* filename, int flags, mode_t mode)
    {
        open(filename, flags, mode);
        std::cout << "Flags = " << flags << std::endl;
        if (flags & O_WRONLY) 
        {
            // do this...
        }
        else if (flags == O_RDONLY) // O_RDONLY == 0
        {
            // do that...
            std::cout << "Hello" << std::endl;
        }
        else
        {
            // this could be determined at compile time already
            throw std::runtime_error{ "Read and write are not supported at the same time currently!" };
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    MyFile file("file.txt", O_RDWR, 0777);
    return 0;
}

The compiler should be able to determine that the exception will be thrown, because the function input is constant. Is there a way to allow for such cases to be detected at compile time?
EDIT: To be clear: I need something in the middle of static_assert() and assert() that will trigger A) at compile time in cases that the constants are determineable B) at runtime if not. Of course this would only be possible with some fancy data flow analysis, but that's what compilers do anyway nowadays I figure..

Function parameters are never constexpr.

You can use template parameters instead of function parameter and then use constexpr if

It is not clear what the expected output is and how it differs from current output.

@user12002570 something like static_assert that should trigger. I don't know if there is a facility to lure the compiler into checking if the flag can be determined at compile time, hence the question.

@user12002570 I know that, but since compilers have grown their capacity over the last years I wouldn't be surprised if there's a way to determine such cases as part of data flow analysis. At least in this simple case.

@user12002570 I could always use template parameters, but let's say I add a facility that invokes this function with runtime-determined flags, I then would want to assert at runtime. So I'm looking for a way to do it only when certain criteria is met, the criteria being that the flags are determineable at compile time, if not it falls back to assert(). Updated the description.

These two dupes should solve the problem: Difference between "if constexpr()" Vs "if()" and Can't use function parameter of a constexpr function in a constant expression

The wonderful thing about triggers is triggers are wonderful things.

Checking the validity of a subset of parameters at compile time is a common problem, and is most notably used in the format string of <fmt>.
You implement this by first noting throw is translated into a compile time error in a constexpr context and combine that with consteval to force a compile time evaluation of the parameter.
struct FileFlags
{
    consteval FileFlags(int flags) : flags{flags}
    {
        if(!(flags & O_WRONLY) && (flags != O_RDONLY))
            throw std::runtime_error{ "Read and write are not supported at the same time currently!" };
    }

    constexpr operator int() const { return flags; }

    int flags = 0;
};

struct MyFile
{
    MyFile(const char* filename, FileFlags flags, mode_t mode)
    {
        open(filename, flags, mode);
        std::cout << "Flags = " << flags << std::endl;
        if (flags & O_WRONLY) 
        {
            // do this...
        }
        else if (flags == O_RDONLY) // O_RDONLY == 0
        {
            std::cout << "Hello" << std::endl;
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    MyFile file("file.txt", O_RDWR, 0777);    // compile time error
    MyFile file("file.txt", O_RDONLY, 0777);  // fine
}

Live

That's an interesting approach, however, what happens when the flags ARE determineable only at runtime? E.g. this wouldn't work. Is there a way to account for this case?

@glades You write a second function/type because those are two different APIs. One is correct by construction and the other is not. Mixing them means it is not correct by construction, defeating the entire point of compile time checking. An analogy is if std::unique_ptr will free your memory on destruction, but only some of the time.

Well constexpr is also kind of a mix since you can construct objects either in a constexpr or non constexpr way. So i figure this is not really an argument. Also there is if consteval to conditionally evaluate at compile time. I can't make the constructor constexpr though, since it uses the open api. But I was just wondering this because the compiler most certainly would be able to predict this branch at compile time, so why isn't it done.

@glades I don't know how to make the compiler chase values down the call stack and produce an error if some condition happens to be statically known, including with if consteval. On the other hand, I don't believe that's a particularly useful construct, because I don't believe it's useful to check the correctness of something only some of the time. constexpr functions are not relevant to the argument because constexpr functions aren't conditionally correct, they're conditionally executed at compile time.

Note:
The answer below was given before the question was altered to request a solution which combines compile-time and run-time (originally it was about a compile-time solution only).
Function parameters are never compile-time constant expressions, and therefore you cannot use them to trigger a static_assert (or other compile time construct).
Instead you can make flags a non-type template parameter, and then combine if constexpr with static_assert to get what you want:
#include <iostream>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <assert.h>

template <int flags>
struct MyFile
{

    MyFile(const char* filename, mode_t mode)
    {
        open(filename, flags, mode);
        std::cout << "flags = " << flags << std::endl;
        if constexpr (flags & O_WRONLY) 
        {
            // do this...
        }
        else if constexpr (flags == O_RDONLY) // O_RDONLY == 0
        {
            // do that...
            std::cout << "Hello" << std::endl;
        }
        else
        {
            // this could be determined at compile time already
            static_assert(false, "Read and write are not supported at the same time currently!");
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    MyFile<O_WRONLY> file1("file.txt", 0777);  // This will NOT trigger static_assert
    //MyFile<O_RDWR> file2("file.txt", 0777);  // This will trigger static_assert
}

Live demo
